# How to force ip resolve process to forward request to another nginx?

Tags: nginx, proxy, proxypass

I have a request "sub1.mydomain.com" coming into an NGINX1.

I'd like NGINX1 to rewrite this request without the subdomain "mydomain.com" and to forward it to an NGINX_sub1.

If I had another request "sub2.mydomain.com" coming into an NGINX1, I'd like NGINX1 to forward "mydomain.com" to NGINX_sub2.

The problem is that "mydomain.com" does not match the ip of NGINX_sub1 or NGINX_sub2.
However as I know the ip of NGINX_sub1 and NGINX_sub2, I'd like to force the ip resolve process.

Is there a way to do that?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can NGINX_sub1 and NGINX_sub2 serve on ip address too? I mean using http://<NGINX_sub2_IP> serve mydomain.com

Comment: Do you mean to *reverse proxy* or *redirect* to the other server?

Comment: @FarhadFarahi no, NGINX_sub1 and NGINX_sub2 are reverse proxies using server_name.

Comment: @RichardSmith I'd like to redirect after rewriting the request (after removing the subdomain).

Comment: In that case the answer is no. When you redirect, the browser will perform the DNS lookup - your server has not control over it. Either fix your DNS or use IP addresses.

Comment: Thanks for your help. There is no way I can dynamically change my /etc/hosts for each request ?